# Windows Phone 8 SQLite async operations hanging indefinitely

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that utilizes SQLite.

I have a problem where some async SQLite operations hang indefinitely (presumably because they are awaited?)

Here is one such operation:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("myDatabase");
var query = conn.Table<MyTable>().Where(x => x.Name == "name");
var result = await query.ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in result)
{
// breakpoint in the code here is never reached
}
```

This is in an async method which returns a Task< string>

This method is called early from the main page code.  The main page never actually builds, as the app is hanging on this method (the screen just says "Loading..." indefinitely until I stop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that further up your call stack (e.g., in your main page code), you are calling `Result` on a `Task<T>`. This will deadlock your program. I explain this in detail in my [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) article and my [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) blog post.

To summarize: when you `await` an uncompleted `Task`, by default the current context is captured and used to restore the remainder of the `async` method after the `Task` completes. In your case, the captured context is a UI context, which only runs on a specified thread (the UI thread).

So, your main page code calls your `async` method which `await`s the `ToListAsync` operation (capturing the UI context). Your `async` code returns an uncompleted `Task` to your main page code which calls `Result` on it. `Result` will (synchronously) block until the `Task` completes. When the `ToListAsync` operation completes, it attempts to execute the rest of your `async` method within the captured (UI) context. But the UI thread is busy; it's blocked waiting for that `Task` to complete. Thus, deadlock.